# Griview Textbox textchanged event not firing

Tags: c#

I've a Gridview with textbox having id gdtxtPayingamount.I've used textchanged event.

In normal case its works fine.

But I've used a javascript function for checking numbers only in the textbox.Javascript works fine and it shows alert when a string is entered.The problem is when number is entered, textchanged event is not firing

Javascript is as follows

```
function CheckNumbers(objRef)
{        
    if(isNaN(objRef.value))
    {
        alert('Enter number only');
        objRef.value="";
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }

}
```

I've called this javascript in gridview rowcreated event

```
protected void gdMainDetails_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {

            TextBox txt = (TextBox)e.Row.FindControl("gdtxtPayingAmount");
            txt.Attributes.Add("onkeyup", "return CheckNumbers(" + txt.ClientID + ")");

    }
}
```

Javascript works fine and it shows alert when a string is entered.The problem is when number is entered textchanged event is not firing

Comment: You don't handle the textchanged event anywhere here?? Also, judging by your javascript I'd expect that the outcome of a number being entered (not displaying an alert) is correct!?

Answer (score 0):

return true if isNaN(objRef.value) == false in JS functiob

Comment: i've made the above changes but event still not firing]